# when to use PCA in this scenario

Tags: pca, cross-validation

I have a feature matrix n by p, where n is small.

I want to do `leave-one-out cross validation (LOOCV)`.Should I apply some dimension reduction technique (like PCA) for once at the very beginning, and perform LOOCV based on the new feature matrix, or apply PCA during each loop of LOOCV (so I get different features matrices in different loop)?

Comment: what you mean by SVD?

Comment: I changed it into PCA.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do it without the sample you are assessing.  In a real scenario when you are using your technique (I don't know if it is classification, regression, etc) the incoming samples will not be in your dataset and thus you will be dealing with something not perfectly fit by your example.  By leaving it in you are effectively overfitting your eigenvectors to contain some of the variance in the sample you are attempting to validate.

Comment: But I just want to decide the optimal dimension k via PCA. Is it more convenient to do it once?

Comment: Its more convenient, but it less correct.  You could run PCA with all of your data initially and determine the cutoff point for whatever level of variance captured you want and then use that K through your cross validation.

Comment: It sounds like a trade-off. Is there any way to show how much it will overfit the data?

Comment: The only tradeoff that I see is the extra time taken to re-calculate PCA, which isn't really that important.  What you could do to see how overfitted it is would be to run it with both methods, the entire dataset and the dataset minus the sample you are considering and see how the results compare.

Comment: IMHO there is no way to know the extend of the bias without measuring it for the actual problem (including the chosen model compexity).

Answer (score 1):

You need to recalculate the PCA for each of the CV surrogate models. Acutally the same already applies to possible previous pre-processing steps that use more than just one case for their calculation (e.g. centering, variance scaling).

> But I just want to decide the optimal dimension k via PCA. Is it more convenient to do it once?

More convenient, maybe, but the result will be overfit as @aplassard explains. This means that **you cannot get the correct $k$ without recalculating the PCA**: doing the PCA on the whole data will yield too high $k$. This will be particularly serious with small $n$.

- When optimizing the model complexity, in theory a constant optimistic bias does not hurt the decision. However, in practice, the optimistically biased "shortcuts" I've encountered so far are not even close to constant but point towareds too high model complexity.
- You say that you are in a small $n$ situation. In that case, is there any chance that you could fix $k$ for the PCA by your knowledge about data and application? In small sample size situations, two things happen

  - You likely do not have enough samples to do the model comparisons necessary for the optimization (fixing of $k$).
  - But nevertheless attempting to do this means that you need a second, outer (independent) validation, thus splitting your data again. Unless, of course,  you'll validate against a data set that you don't have before.

For what it is worth, for the data sets I usually work with (spectroscopic classification, p ca. 10² - 10³, n < 100, sometimes even n < 10 (but 100 - 1000 measurements/rows per patient/batch/case) not recalculating the PCA within the CV loop **underestimates the error typically by a factor of at least 2 - 3**, and I've seen "perfect" classification internally being only 80 % or even 65% with proper separation of test and training data in the crossvalidation.

Comment: what if n is considerably large? Is it the same conclusion?

Comment: @OMG: If n is large enough then PCA with test data == PCA without test data, and it doesn't matter. However, you'd need to show that this is the case, and for that again you need to do the proper calculation (PCA for each of the surrogate models). The one thing that  genuinely  changes is that you may actually be able to get a statistically meaningful model comparison: you can afford the nested validation/double splitting.